# Formatting and ellipses when quoting parts of a list

Tags: orthography, quotes, lists, ellipses

When quoting a list not in its entirety, but only the points 2–5 of 10, how do I set out the quote? Do I add "..." at the beginning and end of the quote as shown below?

> ...
>
> 2. At all material times, [the Subject Member] was a member of the Union.
>
> 3. [The Subject Member] regularly worked out, including weight training.
>
> 4. During the relevant period, on two separate occasions several months apart,he did not attend the meeting.
>
> 5. It is the not common for this person to miss work.
>
> ...

Comment: If it is a direct quote, then you would NOT renumber the list. You would keep it 2, 3, 4, and 5. I don't like the use of ellipses here. You need to make it clear with your lead-in sentence that you are reiterating the four points from some other document.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JLG (why did he not present it as an answer?)

The numbers provide the context; you do not need to indicate items missing from the start of the list, although one might use them at the end to indicate that more follow. One might also use

> [*remainder omitted*]

for explicit clarity.

Note: when displaying computer code, ellipsis are very useful as a placeholder for boiler-plate initialization, etc. Line numbers notwithstanding, code is not an ordered list of statements in this sense.